# Tablesorter exact filter match for number

Tags: filter, numbers, tablesorter

I am using a dropdown filter to filter a table column with numeric values. I read all the documentation on tablesorter, but I am not sure how to get an exact match on the number. When I select 4 in column 8 (zero-based) it shows 4,14 and 42.

Any ideas? I think I need to parse the values but I am not sure how to do it.

This is the script:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var $table = $('table').tablesorter({
        sortList: [[0,0]] ,
        widgets: ["filter"],
        widgetOptions: {
            filter_columnFilters: false,
            filter_reset: '.reset'
        },

        headers: { 
        // Spalte startet mit 0 
            0: {sorter:false},
            1: {sorter:false},
            2: {sorter:false},
            3: {sorter:false},
            4: {sorter:false},
            5: {sorter:false},
            6: {sorter:false},
            7: {sorter:false},
            8: {filter: "digit"}
        }
    }); 
    $.tablesorter.filter.bindSearch( $table, $('.search') );
});
</script>
```

And this is the dropdown list:

```
<label>Liga</label>
<select class="search" style="width:175px;" data-column="8">
    <option selected disabled hidden value=''></option>
    <?php
        $sqlfile = '../sql/leagues.sql';
        $sqlcont = file_get_contents($sqlfile);
        $league_query = mysql_query($sqlcont) or die("Anfrage sql nicht erfolgreich");
        while ($filter = mysql_fetch_array($league_query)){
            echo "<option value='".$filter['LID']."'>".$filter['LID']."</option>";
    }?>
</select>
```

And finally the tableheaders:

```
    <thead>
    <tr>            
        <th>Datum</th>
        <th>Uhrzeit</th>
        <th>Spielklasse</th>
        <th>Liga</th>
        <th>Team A</th>
        <th>Team B</th>
        <th>Ergebnis</th>
        <th>Auswertung</th>     
        <th>SID</th>            
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter widget is set up by default to match results. If you want to exactly match a result, add an equal sign (`=`) or quote (`"` or `'`) to the end of the query. Try [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/3646/) & use `10=` in the second column to only show values of `10`.

On [this demo page](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html), a full list of filter widget search types are available.

If you want the results to *always* be an exact match, then check out [this demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-custom.html#custom_filter_function) that shows how to use the `filter_functions` option to always return an exact match - that code should work for both text and numbers, if not, then change the `===` to `==` as follows:

```
filter_functions : {

  // Exact match only
  1 : function(e, n, f, i, $r) {
    return e == f;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I read this part, but I guess it only work on text. But it works fine. Thanks.